# Crop background CSS

Tags: css, background-image

[image]**HTML:**

```
<div id="large">
  <div id="medium">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#large {
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  background:url('image.jpg');
}

#medium {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  opacity:.5;
}

#medium div {
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  background:?;
}
```

Now for `#medium div` I want to ignore the background of `#medium`, achieving a background image without any red hue.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not quiet getting your question

Comment: then set the `#medium div` `background` to your desired background color.

Comment: You can't remove the parent background but you can add a new one. Aligning it _might_ be a challenge (or not).

Comment: `#large` will have background image.jpg, #medium red with half opacity, now innermost div has no background color/image, i want to show the part of image.jpg as it's background, ignoring red background beneath it

Answer (score 0):

Can we do some trick for that by using same background url for child div too.

```
#medium div {
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
   background:url('image.jpg');
  background-position-x:34px;/*adjust yourself*/
  background-position-y:45px;/*adjust yourself*/

}
```

[view jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/TVK9h/2/)